# Panorama viewers based on Javascript

Tags: javascript

Are there panorama viewers out there that are not Flash, Silverlight, Java or Quicktime based? Is anyone on this list working on one of these or using one? :)

I want to be able to program hotspots into the panorama so that it can trigger other media such as audio, video or perhaps another panorama.

We're trying to think of a panorama viewing solution that is not plug-in dependent.

I did some initial search and here's [a javascript solution](http://www.openstudio.fr/Afficher-des-panoramas-spheriques?lang=en). But the performance is not that good, and I don't know if it support hotspots.
Here's [a list of pano players](http://www.panoramaphotographer.com/comparisons/), all of them are plugin based...one is actually Shockwave!

Comment: I would say that this is the sort of thing that belongs on StackOverflow, not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Google Street View with a [custom panorama](http://weblab.ab-c.nl/streetview). [Another example showing how it can be standalone](http://alecmgo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/streetviewpano/streetview-custom-simple.html). Note you can customise what controls are there etc

Comment: Cool! This gets me really close to what I need. Now I need to figure out how to deal with hotspots and such. Any ideas Julian?

Comment: I didn't take a close look at the code for how the panorama is done, but you might be able to take advantage of image map: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp

Comment: milesmeow yes streetview has an event api that tells you when things change. See for instance Expedia Hotel View 
http://www.expediahotelview.com for 2D overlays and The Editors for 3D integrated overlay (see the red arrow they add) http://www.editorsofficial.com/

Comment: @Juian - that looks really promising. I can't seem to find the red arrow on editorsofficial.com.

Comment: @Juian - the 2D overlays don't stick to certain objects in the scene. I'm sure one can do it through some calculation of one's own, but does the API do it for you?

Comment: Sorry wrong link here we go http://www.editorsofficial.com/streetview/

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#browsersupport ... browser support for V3 and V2 of the API. We're targeting IE6 so we won't be able to use custom panoramas!  Drats!

Comment: IE6? You're kidding. Who does that any more? Not even Microsoft. Try http://www.google.com/chromeframe

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's Seadragon project includes a [fairly sweet JavaScript-based viewer](http://www.seadragon.com/developer/ajax/).

Unfortunately, [Zoom.it](http://zoom.it/), the rebranded "production-ready" version of Seadragon only supports a Silverlight viewer (as far as I can tell). Worse, Microsoft never opened up the Seadragon format and required a web API or a Windows utility to create images.